# What is a good beginner species?

Tags: pet-selection, snakes, exotic-pets

I'm thinking about getting a snake and I want to know what is the best breed to start with. I've worked with lots of snakes so far at work, but I would like to get one of my own and I don't know what breed to get. I've handled Corn Snakes, King Snakes, and Eastern Indigo's all the way up to Pythons. I really enjoy these animals but I would love to know what would be good to start with.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of experience with multiple species, so what criteria are you looking for to define "best breed to start with"?

Comment: I'm looking for a snake that doesn't mind being out and held. I know that is something you have to "train" them to do or get use to. I honestly don't know where to start to get my first snake. Not on where to get them but what is the best breed to have.

Comment: The folks I know who has had boas has been quite happy with them; they seem very content to treat humans as harmess warm trees. This is not a recommendation, just a data point. I have no idea how endangered the species may be or if it's an invasive hazard if it escapes.

Comment: I think it's much better to encourage a beginner to start with a corn snake than close the question. It is not really a matter of opinion. These snakes are (1) well tempered / docile, (2) robust, (3) easy to feed, (4) a manageable size, (5) easy to get hold of, (6) inexpensive, (7) easy to house (temperature/humidity). How many species in the centre of that Venn diagram?  I think this should be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "starter snake" - they all have different requirements and needs.
It 100% depends what you want, and what you like the look of.
If you like pythons and heavy bodied constrictors, it would be foolish to get a Corn Snake, because people say they are good for 'beginners'.
There are many snakes in rescues due to this - people are advised to get them as a starter, but they were not really what they were looking for.

Pick the snake you like, research its care, speak to people who keep them and decide if its for you.

My first snake was a Boa - I got it because I like the look of boas...

Comment: Also - "Species" not breed. Breed typically refers to types of a distinct domesticated species, eg dogs or chickens.